# iperf connect failed: Connection refused

Tags: linux, iperf, failed

`iperf -c 192.168.3.2 -i 2

connect failed: Connection refused`

3.2 is another machine. I think the port might be blocked.

How can I make this work?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but: are you running "iperf -s" on 192.168.3.2?

Comment: Another reason to get this error is running the IPerf server in UDP mode and client in TCP mode and vice versa.

Comment: Make sure Server & Client versions are the same... I had the same problem!

Comment: Make sure you are using same version of iperf

Answer (score 26):

You also get a "connection refused" error when you use an iperf v3 client to send to an iperf v2 server.

The message is slightly different though:

```
iperf3: error - unable to connect to server: Connection refused
```

As the iperf3 doc states, they are not compatible (at least up to version 3.1.2). You can check the version on both server and client with

```
iperf -v
```

Comment: This is what happened to me. The windows version had the newest one (3.1.3) while for arch installing iperf gave me an old 2.0.5. Installing iperf3 on arch gave me the newest version, after which all went well.

Comment: Even in 2022 this is so much useful ! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I doubt that this is a firewall issue. Usually, firewalls employ the DROP rule for packets that are not allowed. A "connection refused" means that there is no application listening on the port it tries to connect to. The destination host indicates this with a corresponding ICMP message to the source.

In order to run iperf you must have a server running on the machine which you iperf to.  To do this run `iperf -s` on the server.  After that you can then run `iperf -c <server IP or hostname> -i 2`

After running this you will get an ouput that looks something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to <server IP>, TCP port 5000
TCP window size:   256 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 123.123.123.123 port 4000 connected with 123.123.123.123 port 5000
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.1 GBytes  1.09 Gbits/sec
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-C` command line option to force both ends to use an older version of the protocol and this will prevent the error.

From the help output:

```
-C, --compatibility      for use with older versions does not sent extra msgs
```

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off any firewall on the machines.  On many linux distros, you can do

```
service firewall off
```

to disable the firewall.