# my iperf connection test client side keeps showing connection refused

Tags: vlan, iperf

I am trying to setup an iperf test but the client side keeps getting connection refused message.

```
Server side:
ubuntu@webserver1:~$ iperf -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
ubuntu@webserver1:~$


Client side: 
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo iperf -c 192.168.1.2
connect failed: Connection refused
test@ubuntu:~$
```

The command I am using is exactly like this guide here: http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php

and I saw some previous iperf questions, but they do not provide a solution on what's wrong here:
[iperf connect failed: Connection refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/280961/iperf-connect-failed-connection-refused)
https://serverfault.com/questions/643420/network-connectivity-reachability-between-nodes-located-in-the-same-lan-using
[Iperf bidirectional bandwidth measurement](https://serverfault.com/questions/396531/iperf-bidirectional-bandwidth-measurement)

I have a vlan id setup for my network, and both my server and client are on the same vlan id, and they can ping each other. So I don't think the it's cause by a vlan id.
Its not the firewall either. ufw is disabled. 
I am running ubuntu server 14 on both client and server.

thanks everyone

Comment: You are starting the server first aren't you? The way you've shown the commands implies that you're trying to start the client first (which won't work).

Comment: hey @Paul Haldane, I am starting the server first, I copied the order wrong, sorry for the confusion